# Context suggestion for yasnippet

Tags: company-mode, yasnippet, auto-complete-mode

I would like to create a yasnippet snippet as follow: pressing `weather` I would like that would be inserted the following text `current weather =` with the cursor after the `=` (this can be done with `current weather = $1`).
I would so like that a context menu with some suggestion will appear, like `sunny`, `rainy`, and so on.

How can I do this? Have I got to use in some ways autocomplete or company?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with [yas-choose-value](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-reference.html#yas-choose-value):

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# key: weather
# --
current weather = ${1:$$(yas-choose-value '("sunny" "rainy"))}
```

Please read through the [writing snippets](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) section of the
documentation because it answers many of your recently asked
questions.